# SQL subquery error giving can't specify against target

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, subquery

```
update customers 
set transaction_id = ( 
    select transaction_id from transactions
    where transaction_type IN (select transaction_type from customers where id = 1)
);
```

gives the error 1093. You can't specify target table for update in where clause?  Anyone know why I am not allowed to use this Subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error 1093 comes from mysql, so i think you misstagged it.

But basically you need to create a subquery, so the database, doesn't use customers, which you are trying to change.

You must be sure that the subquery only reuturns one scalar value

```
CREATE tABLe customers (id int , transaction_id int)
```

```
CREATE tABLE transactions (transaction_id int,transaction_type int)
```

```
update customers 
set transaction_id = ( 
    select transaction_id from transactions
    where transaction_type IN (select transaction_type from (SELECT transaction_type  FROM customers where id = 10) c )
);
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fM---CDA)

Comment: I also needed to add a where clause as to not update all tables I forgot that.  Thank you nbk. I'm not sure why MySQL does this.  I have researched the reason but found nothing that really explained this behavior.

Comment: the basic problem is that evey databse loops row by row and so changes customer, with every row, so the sub select query woulöd always change at the same time, which would cause in worst case a never ending update. with the added subquery a temporay table which stays always the same, thus can be used freely, without causing problems